# What should we defer in ctypes? ctypes.open? Function defintions?

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

For performance, efficiency, etc.: Does ctypes.open have a large overhead? Should it be deferred till just before use? Or is it ok if I open like a bunch of dll's right on load of my addon?

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm');

var lib = {
  blah: ctypes.open('blah.dll'),
  ctypes.open('blah2.dll'),
  ctypes.open('blah3.dll'),
  ctypes.open('blah4.dll'),
  ctypes.open('blah5.dll'),
  ctypes.open('blah6.dll'),
};

for (var l in lib) {
  lib[l].close();
}
```

Should we also defer function defintions or is that light lifting like:

```
var SetForegroundWindow = lib.user32.declare('SetForegroundWindow', ctypes.winapi_abi, ctypes.bool,
    ctypes.int32_t
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make (some) sense to delay the loading of a dll that is not already mapped into the virtual address space of the firefox process.

But user32.dll is a dependency of xul.dll.

So when you `ctypes.open('user32.dll')` all that happens is that the reference counter of the particular dll is increased by one. Hardly the subject of optimization (premature or not).

Comment: Thats interesting thanks man. How can i find out if ff is using a certain dll? Like what would I search on mxr? Also this guy here does lazy loading of function declarations of ctypes, is it worth the trouble? https://github.com/foudfou/FireTray/blob/0dd01042ccf298f5dd507c5151923d605ab5319e/src/modules/ctypes/ctypes-utils.jsm#L186 and uses it here: https://github.com/foudfou/FireTray/search?q=lazy_bind

Comment: You can use the [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) with the /dependents switch. `dumpbin` ships with the Windows SDK but probably there is a ton of tools that will do the same. The function declaration, on Windows, will result to a `GetProcAddress` call. Again, I don't see what could be the overhead of a table lookup and the initialization of a function pointer. If someone does lazy loading as a matter of principle, that's fine with me.

Comment: Thanks man I'm not going to lazy load then it's just too much crap to worry about for no benefit haha. Ill check the dll's. The same applies for *nix and mac huh?

Comment: I think other OSes have similar implementations. If you want a GUI tool try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)